# Error in SAP B1 .b1f forms: "Failed to create form. Please check the form attributes."

Tags: sapb1, sap-business-one-di-api

I created an addon with B1 Studio. I have 3 .b1f forms. The solution works well running from Visual Studio on my laptop.

I moved the solution to a server and I am getting the below error when I click on the form to open.

[image]

bin folder and .b1s file below:

[image]

How do I fix this, any ideas?

SAP Business One 10.0 version for SAP HANA (10.00.220) SP 2308 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure that there is b1s file in bin folder on server?